# Router is down when I connect ethernet cable to PC

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ethernet, hardware-failure

I have a wireless router (Comtrend AR-5315U) that randomly stops synchronizing (more of less 80% of times) when I connect it to a particular PC using an Ethernet cable or, if already connected, when the machine boots up.

The problem does not occur with other routers using the same cables and connections.

This PC has dual boot (Windows 10 and Ubuntu) so I don't think is a configuration issue since the problem is occurring with both OSes.

Do you have an idea what's the cause of it?

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by synchronizing?

Comment: I mean DSL sync test.My diagnostics page shows Test xDSL Synchronization: FAIL and the router Internet won't work.

Comment: Sounds like you should contact your ISP if that's the case.  If it shows synchronization failed I'm not too sure how any pcs would successfully connect to the Internet.  Do other pcs show a different sync status when you look at the diagnostic page?

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the diagnostic page and add it to your question?  If you do not have enough rep to post a picture, upload it to some public image hosting site and post a link to the screenshot that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've worked it out.

My router was connected to a power strip where there were other devices connected too (the computer, the printer, the screen, the speakers, the scanner...).

It looks like the culprit was not the computer but the scanner. After disconnecting it from the power strip I've had not more errors with my connection.

Cheers,

Comment: Who woulda thunk it?  Thanks for closing the loop on your question.  If you accept your answer by clicking the checkmark next to it, that will indicate that the problem has been solved.